# Creating an html grid of squares in my background that won't intefere with elements in the foreground

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a grid of squares in the background of my webpage which already has a lot of different elements carrying content. My trouble now is that the div squares I'm creating are intefereing with the layout of everything else. I've tried setting z-index of the parent div of my square divs to like -3, but that doesn't seem to really help. What's are some good css rules that can help me sort this out? Thanks

Comment: Try positioning the grid squares absolutely, and then set the z-index of the content higher than the z-index of the parent container of the squares

Comment: Put grid squares in wrapper div with a low z-index then set absolute position to wrapper div and high z-index on main content.

Comment: All right sweet, so I set my parent div to position absolute as well as a z-index of -3, and it worked!

Comment: If it worked like you wanted it to, I will post it as an answer. Did it?

Comment: Well the parent div has to be position absolute, not the squares themselves because that just causes all the squares to stack on top of each other, so I think msdesdev is the closest to the solution.

Comment: Yes, naturally, the child elements will be positioned relative to the parent container. So you only need to set the container's position to be absolute. And it seems like someone has already posted the correct answer :)

Comment: Yeah sure, go for it

Answer (score 0):

Create the tiles in Photoshop and then save it out as a *.PNG or *.GIF. These have the smallest file sizes.

Use this within your container or wrapper div:

```
.contentContainer {
    background:url(images/image_background.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

1. background:url set's the URL of the image.
2. top left sets the position. You can use just "top", "center", "bottom", etc. or "top left", "top bottom" to align it how you need it.
3. no-repeat makes it so the BG image doesn't "tile" over and over again as you might have experienced with say, your windows wallpaper. It looks tacky.

Comment: The OP hasn't specified that the grid squares are images. They could be divs with different content.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it divs because I want to manipulate the color of each square later. I don't think I can use an image file in this case.

Comment: Hmm..when creating a website and using industry's best practices I can't really see this not being an image seeing that he mentioned there's a lot of pre-existing content already on the page and interfering with the mentioned content. I suppose pyramidface can clarify. If this is the case I can delete my answer and adjust it accordingly. It seems like one heck of a mess if they're squares, say 10-20 squares, enough to fill a background + the many elements caring content as he mentioned. It could be done, though. Let us know, pyramid.

Comment: Roger that, pyramid. Can you post a URL to the page you're working on or input the code into jsfiddle.net and supply the link, even if the code is messed up. Given your preface, I think we'll be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: It's fine now, it's been figured it out. Check out the comments in the original post. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, it may be best to use an image for this situation. Regardless, here is a jsfiddle showing how to use absolute positioning on the wrapper for the background squares to take it out of the flow of the document: http://jsfiddle.net/eL1w7kdz/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background-squares">
        <div>Square 1</div><div>Square 2</div><div>Square 3</div><div>Square 4</div><div>Square 5</div><div>Square 6</div><div>Square 7</div><div>Square 8</div><div>Square 9</div><div>Square 10</div><div>Square 11</div><div>Square 12</div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin bibendum neque a venenatis dictum. Donec fringilla euismod sodales.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer leo ipsum, aliquam sit amet ligula non, fringilla commodo diam. Vivamus tortor mi, blandit vel mi at, feugiat rhoncus libero. Donec volutpat, tellus nec sagittis tempor, leo dui sollicitudin turpis, et fringilla nisl metus ac libero. In augue mauris, malesuada id ipsum vel, hendrerit vulputate justo.</p><p>Morbi aliquam est non fringilla cursus. Sed at felis et magna vehicula egestas. Integer finibus lectus lorem, a commodo nulla rutrum eu. Sed eleifend condimentum tristique. Curabitur eu nisl mi. Etiam imperdiet nisl metus, at iaculis ex consequat eget. In non eros dolor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background-squares {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

#background-squares div {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#main-content {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The OP has mentioned in the comments that he will manipulate the colors of each div, so I think that div may be a better solution than images in this situation.